GCP: Ansible: Need to write a GCP dynamic inventory with the project labels as filter
have 3 GCP folders,

folder_a
folder_b
folder_c

need to write a dynamic inventory file to get the VMs in the list of folders.
I have 10 projects in each folder but I want to filter the project with the project label "severity=critical" . I need to only get the list of VMs from the projects having that label.
I tried ,
--- plugin: google.cloud.google_compute 
but there is no option to filter the project labels. only VM level labels can be filtered
